# JSON POST requests empty response on Mongo

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, post

I'm try to post From HTML Form To MongoDB Atlas and following the tutorial.

used:

- express js
- body-parser
- mongoose

I can create a request but no content.

I have no clue where's the problem.

I'm supposed to show the document in MongoDB Atlas

```
{
  "_id": "a13d1s2bc12as3a2",
  "name": "Name",
  "password": "password",
  "_v": 0
}
```

but now like this:

```
{
  "_id": "a13d1s2bc12as3a2",
  "_v": 0
}
```

I can connect the mongoDB.
Here my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const urlencoded = require("body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded");
                               
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//connect mongodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://comp3421:password@cluster.o06sg.mongodb.net/db", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

//create dataSchema
const notesSchema = {
    username:String,
    password:String
}

const Note = mongoose.model("Note", notesSchema);

//get function
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/try.html");
})

//insert into mongodb
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    let newNote = new Note({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    newNote.save();
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server is running on 3000")
})
```

This part is try.html and the main part of the html:

```
            <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="f input">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </div>

                <div class="f input">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" >
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create account">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse request body.
You have to mention below line.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```